# Typescript extends object and exclude Date type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to exclude `Date` type from `object` type. I have the following type for error within a form. However i am running into a problem where `Date` type is part of `object`.

```
export type FieldErrors<FormValues> = {
  [Key in keyof FormValues]?: FormValues[Key] extends any[]
    ? FormValues[Key][number] extends object
      ? FieldErrors<FormValues[Key][number]>[]
      : FieldError
    : FormValues[Key] extends object // this is the issue bit when extend object
    ? FieldErrors<FormValues[Key]>
    : FieldError
};


type FormData = {
  stringField: string;
  numberField: string;
  dateField: Date;
};

{errors.dateField && errors.dateField.message} // This result in error because Date type is object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for a [negated type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) like `FormValues[Key] extends object & not Date` - they are not out yet.

Instead you can add a conditional step that checks for `Date`. `Date` is a subtype/more specific type than `object`, so this step should happen before the `FormValues[Key] extends object` check.

A good rule is to go from the most specific to the most general case. Here is an example:

```
interface FieldError { message: string }

export type FieldErrors<FormValues> = {
    [Key in keyof FormValues]?: FormValues[Key] extends any[]
    ? FormValues[Key][number] extends object
    ? FieldErrors<FormValues[Key][number]>[]
    : FieldError
    : FormValues[Key] extends Date // add conditional check for Date
    ? FieldError
    : FormValues[Key] extends object // ... before object check
    ? FieldErrors<FormValues[Key]>
    : FieldError
};

/*
type MyFormErrors = {
  stringField?: FieldError | undefined;
  numberField?: FieldError | undefined;
  dateField?: FieldError | undefined;
}
*/
type MyFormErrors = FieldErrors<FormData>

declare const errors: MyFormErrors
errors.dateField && errors.dateField.message // FieldError.message: string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=75&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYFEpQD2UyA3sgLYQDO1cA5hAFzLVhSj3IC%20AsAFACIADwAOxMMjABPUSnRY8BYtQA8qYhQBqcTAFcaAPmQBeMgOSXkAbQDSEaclDIA1g8Iw0mnfpoBdAH4WDShtXQNqOwc-ZBFIEGxqZDgQaWs-CysAr1CfCKjpP2sQPQoAI2gYuIgEpMIygCsIBDBMy2yFHHwiKDUQsN9I%200Li0oqoP0N0tuRgjC7lKBng73CaAqrheMTkABE4SBmO%20aUe5ZyB-OHN7brG5tb%20K2RjxW6VdVXBjcNzztPiAJuABuAQCGRyC77MBwUzmJ5WNgcED0f4sJGcUEIywlcrQNGsdiYmbYA4QAnQiBYkFg-gQlAAWWk-XevTh-1ZfU00Lgv0E-GwzUwcCgKAQhBAbFii2oLCZLJlQhlADpSZB-sgAGSa6U9aiqsn-ZVUWgMFAAenNaBOrONNDojHRRJRtKAA)